# Напишите программу для решения задачи, используя одномерный массив:

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Дана последовательность из n различных целых чисел. Найти сумму ее членов, расположенных между максимальным и минимальным значениями (в сумму включить и оба этих числа).

Помогите пожалуйста. Массив составлен, максимальное и минимальное значение найдено, как найти сумму между этими значениями? никак не получается...

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    int a[100], sum = 0;

    cout << "Введите элементы массива: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int min, max;
    min = max = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (a[i] > max) max = a[i];
        if (a[i] < min) min = a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Минимальное значение: " << min << endl;
    cout << "Максимальное значение: " << max << endl;
    if (min < max) {
        for (int i = min + 1; i = max; ++i) sum = sum + a[i];
        cout << "Сумма: " << sum << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Думаю, намека будет достаточно... Сохраняйте не только минимальное и максимальное значение, но и их индексы (не просто `max = a[i]`, но что-то типа `max = a[maxidx = i]`.

Comment: @Harry хорошо, теперь выводит на экран сумму, но считает все равно не правильно.. в этом промежутке, все так же остается или нет?
if (min < max) {
  for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i) sum = sum + a[i];
  cout << "Сумма: " << sum << endl;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Времени все объяснять нет...

```
int min, max;
int min_idx = 0, max_idx = 0;
min = max = a[0];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (a[i] > max) max = a[max_idx = i];
    else if (a[i] < min) min = a[min_idx = i];
}
cout << endl;
cout << "Минимальное значение: " << min << endl;
cout << "Максимальное значение: " << max << endl;

if (min_idx > max_idx) { int tmp = min_idx; min_idx = max_idx; max_idx = tmp; }
for (int i = min_idx; i <= max_idx; ++i) sum += a[i];
cout << "Сумма: " << sum << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать в 1 строчку, используя стандартный алгоритм `std::accumulate` с параметрами `std::min_element` и `std::max_element`